# How would the following situation look like, without having these classes in the same file?

Tags: java, object, structure, modularity

Good day all,

So as the title says; I am wondering how the following situation would look like without having these classes in the same file.

This example comes from this: '[using a table in a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158233/using-a-table-in-a-different-class)' specific thread, the 4th answer given.

```
class A {

   private JTable myJTable;


   public JTable getMyJTable() {
      return myJTable;
   }

   public void setMyJTableValue(Object value) {
   // set the value accordingly
   }
}


class B {

   private A a;

   public void methodWithAccessToA() {
      // business logic ...
      a.setMyJTableValue(myBusinessValue);
      // ...
      a.getMyJTable().setValue(myBusinessValue);
   }
}
```

If these were two classes on two different files, it would mean class B needs to create an new object-instance of A first (a = new A)  which would make it lose it's possibility of updating thé table what is needed to be updated.

Like this scenario: 
[separated files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIuTv.png)

So what is the best way to deal with such scenario? All I could think of was creating one Main class that contains and passes along created objects from class A and B but I think I may be on the wrong side there.

Comment: Are these two classes 'A' and 'B' defined within another class that's not shown?  Right now looks like two separate classes, no inner classes?

Comment: No, my bad, it seemed I was using the term 'inner-class' wrong, as this is not a 'class within a class' - situation but two classes in the same page.

Comment: What does *"on the same page"* mean?

Comment: I mean the opposite of this example:

http://nl.tinypic.com/r/x1bnzn/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put them in different files, you would have to declare the classes public. Then each class would have to be in the name-of-the-class.java

Comment: Which would still have them both at one .java , is there no other way around this?

Comment: The first class functions as a name in a .java that contains two classes? What if I want the .java to be named 'Tabs.java' but my classes are 'tab1.class'  and 'tab2.class' ?

Comment: Then to get them on different pages (files) you need to declare one class tab1 in file tab1.java and the other tab2.class in tab2.java. Both would have to be declared public.

Comment: Public or not, I would still need to create an object of that class like A = new A()  instead of already having an 'a' object.  

When a new object of the class that creates a table is created, the table that needs to be updated is no longer reached because it's a new object. A getter() would get a different table object as the one to be updated

Comment: In both, your version and my version, the JTable belongs to class A. In class B (By the way you aren't instantiating A) when you call setMyTable(), I'm assuming you call it with a new JTable. That will set the class A JTable. On the next line, you do a getMyJTable, which returns the one you set in the previous line, then it sets a value in the returned JTable using the value (myBusinessValue). This is called encapsulation in Object oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

We've been conversing through comments on my previous answer and I realized it wasn't pseudo-code. I'll comment your code.

```
    /** This is a new class definition, by declaring it public, 
         it has to be in it's own file called A.java */
 public class A {
        // create an instantiation of JTable, call it myTable
        private JTable myJTable = new JTable();



        public JTable getMyJTable() {
            return myJTable;
       }

        // is someone calls this method, they override my myTable value.
        public void setMyJTableValue(JTable value) {
            // Someone is telling me what to set myTable to.
            this.myTable = value;
        }
    }


    /** This is a new class definition, by declaring it public, 
         it has to be in it's own file called B.java*/
    public class B {

        // This creates a new class A in class B, you are calling it "a"
        private A a = new A();

        public void methodWithAccessToA() {
             // business logic ...
              // Create class B's version of a JTable, tell class A to use it
              JTable myBusinessValue = new JTable();
             a.setMyJTableValue(myBusinessValue);
             // ... This gets a JTable from a, then calls the setValue() on the JTable
            a.getMyJTable().setValue(whatever JTable is expecting);
        }
    }
```